# Upgrade Resteasy 2.2.1.GA to 2.3.2 in JBoss 6

Tags: jboss, resteasy

We are using JBoss AS 6.1.0.Final which comes with Resteasy 2.2.1.GA by default.  However, I've been tasked to use Resteasy 2.3.2.  What is the proper way to upgrade Resteasy in JBoss? I haven't been able to locate decent procedures on how to do so.

If it cannot be upgraded, how can I ensure my application uses Resteasy 2.3.2 JARs?  Simply by placing them in my app's lib directory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I just updated JBoss AS 6.1.0.Final to RestEasy 2.3.3 by doing the following:

1. I deleted all jar files under "jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deployers/resteasy.deployer", except for "jboss-as-resteasy-6.1.0.Final.jar"
2. I downloaded RestEasy from [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resteasy/files/Resteasy%20JAX-RS/2.3.3.Final/) and unpacked the zip file
3. I copied all jar files from "resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final/lib" to "jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deployers/resteasy.deployer"

Do note that the Apache Commons libraries are older in the RESTeasy 2.3.4 (and subsequently in 2.3.3) than the ones packaged in JBoss 6.1.0GA. It's worth considering leaving those as is; ie. not downgrading them.